# Issue with `event_generate` method in Tkinter not triggering `<ButtonRelease>` event

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, events

I am facing an issue with the `event_generate` method in Tkinter, and I'm looking for some guidance on why it might not be working as expected.

**Simplified code sample:**

```
import tkinter as tk

def button_release_event(event):
    print("Button released")

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text="Click me")
label.pack()

label.bind("<ButtonRelease>", button_release_event)


label.event_generate("<ButtonRelease>")

root.mainloop()
```

**Problem:**

In the provided code, I have a Label widget that is bound to the `<ButtonRelease>` event. When the left mouse button is released after clicking the Label, it should print "Button released" to the console. However, the event doesn't seem to be generated when I use the `label.event_generate("<ButtonRelease>")` line.

**Question:**

Why is the `event_generate` method not triggering the `<ButtonRelease>` event as expected in this case?
Can I use a different approach or workaround to simulate a button release event for this Label?
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you!

**Environment:**

macOS, Python version: 3.11

Comment: This seems to be working for me on Windows 11, Python v3.11.3. How is it not working on yours?

Comment: You don't have to use ```label.event_generate("<ButtonRelease>")```, right?

Comment: It looks like the event is ignored before `mainloop()` is executed.  It works if you delay the call a bit using `.after()`: `root.after(100, label.event_generate, "<ButtonRelease>")`.

Comment: @acw1668, wouldn't lambda functions do better than multiple parameters?

Comment: @drEinstein Why do you think that using lambda is better when lambda is not necessary?

Comment: @acw1668 Neater and what happens if you want to post multiple arguments?

Comment: @drEinstein Note that `.after()` support multiple arguments for the given function.

Comment: @acw1668 Root is not available in my case but I used `after()` method on parent like this; I also used `update()`. Still, event seems to be ignored.

Comment: @acw1668. Ok. Sorry for my ignorance. I didn't know :D

Comment: @Mania There is `root` in your code.  It works for me in my Windows 7 with Python 3.8.18.  May be trying with longer delay.

Comment: @acw1668 The code is simplified here. In my original case, I'm using lambda, and event happens when generated by user but it won't using `event_generate` method.

Comment: `label.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", button_release_event)` #Left or  click `label.bind("<ButtonRelease-3>", button_release_event)` # right click

Comment: @Mania, then provide your original code!

Comment: @drEinstein The original code is convoluted and long. But I'm wondering other than being ignored in `mainloop()`, what else can affect that? The event is bound and confirmed by printing `.bind()`, but still it won't generate without user interaction.

Comment: Does `event_generate()` works when it is called inside a function triggered by a button?

Comment: Then I wonder why it does not work when using `.after()`.  Does your application take a long time to start up?  If yes, then try longer delay when using `.after()`.